# SESSION persists in not staying active for as Long as I define

Tags: php, session-cookies, session-variables

I have tried lots of suggestions and alternatives, from controlling via php code and server configuration to keeping sessions on my website active for a maximum of 4 hours (without user interaction). The methods I've been using just don't work. After the session start, if there is no user activity, in 30 minutes the session is automatically destroyed when my goal is 4 hours maximum.

**Options after Research I've tried:**

- in the past it could easily solve it with Meta Refresh directly in the HTML, but it was giving a very boring user experience, because the forms restarted every 15 minutes.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">`

- I'm currently trying to configure via `setcookie` and `php.ini` configuration, but the session won't hold for the 4 hours (14400 seconds) that i need. The expiration time is well defined in the Cookies in the browser (as you can see in the image), but in practice what happens is that it just can keep alive a maximum of 30 min (without any user activity). - am I missing some important detail?

```
<?php
session_start();

$start = time();
$expire = $start+14400;

session_regenerate_id();
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),$expire);

// code continues
?>
```

php.ini - config

```
date.timezone = "Europe/London"
session.cookie_httponly = 1
session.name = "SID"
session.gc_maxlifetime = 14400
session.save_path = "/opt/alt/php74/var/lib/php/session"
```

Cookie Info in Browser

[image: Cookie on Browser]

Comment: That `session.save_path`, is that used exclusively by your application/site, or do other projects on the server perhaps use the same path to store their session data? If so, then the garbage collector triggered by those would clear your session files after whatever shorter max lifetime those projects might have configured.

Comment: @CBroe, the `session.save_path` used are exclusively for my WebSite.